# how to replace source " https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" in the wordpress backend?

Tags: posts

i got a problem in my blog [https://www.imhunk.com](https://www.imhunk.com/) backend, when i edit a post, it takes a long time to open the post and i tested the network in chrome, it shows the source https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css failed to download, below is the screenshot
[image]

as my hosting is located in China, the goolgle source is blocked , so my questions: where is the https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css and is there any method to replace it to other source that can be access in China?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the wordpress core doesn't call a external server for assets. you must have a plugin that produce that. try to desactivate plugins one after another to find which one do that.

Comment: what mmm is saying. normally wordpress does not require jquery ui or any other external files. guess the default themes may use googlefonts or so, but i am not even sure about that. so eather it is your theme, that requires jquery ui or some plugin you are using. a good start would be to search inside functions.php in your current theme folder..